# Redirect not work fine in Laravel and show a message before redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a register form, in this form I get some data like phone number

After submit form user will be redirect to register phone page to register phone with posted code.

When user submit form, SMS will be send but user will be redirect to register form and show this message :

[image: Redirect Message]

```
{"result":{"code":200,"message":success"},"items":[...]} Redirecting to 
https://thermotajhiz.com/register/phone
```

But user have to redirect and stay in token form.

This is **register** controller :

```
$request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'phone_number' => [
            'required',
            'min:11',
            'max:11',
            Rule::unique('users')
        ]
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
    ]);

    $code = ActiveCode::generateCode($user);
    $request->session()->flash('phone', $request['phone_number']);
    $request->session()->flash('auth', ['user_id' => $user->id]);

    $user->notify(new ActiveCodeNotification($code, $request['phone_number']));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return redirect()->route('register.token');
```

And this is Routes for register and token :

```
Route::get('/register/phone', 'Auth\RegisterController@showTokenForm')->name('register.token');
Route::post('/register/phone', 'Auth\RegisterController@postTokenForm');
```

And this is **showTokenForm** method :

```
public function showTokenForm(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->session()->has('phone')) {
        return redirect(route('register'));
    }

    $request->session()->reflash();

    return view('auth.register-token');
}
```

I check `session('phone')` And the session will be registered correctly.

**UPDATE**

I don't have session in `showTokenForm` method !

Why I have this message and I can't see token form ?

This is a preview of redirects :

[image]

Comment: because you don't pass phone as a param so when it checks the phone params it didn't found it and it redirects you back to register as you did (`return redirect(route('register'));`)

-- the redirect trace works only with get

Comment: @PsyLogic How can I do this here?

Comment: Use Unit test it is better to test your requests and redirects 
or test it yourself on your browser